# Scientific basis for the existence of microaggression

Tags: behavior, aggression

Microaggression has been used in the articles and has become more commonplace in the public discourse.

I remember reading articles proposing existence of microaggressions but have not seen any psychology lab research confirming its existence. There has been vehement hostility from conservative commentators claiming that microaggression is a pseudoscience based on "biased interview questions, reliance on narrative and small numbers of respondents, problems of reliability, issues of replicability, and ignoring alternative explanations" [- Microaggression article on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microaggression)

What is the best evidence so far for the existence of microaggression?